# I can't get password reset for LoL on Outlook

Tags: email, outlook.com, account-recovery, password-reset

I have an outlook email for many years that receives all emails as expected but recently I needed to reset my password for a League of Legends account. The password reset email never appears. Not in junk, no senders blocked, etc.

Oddly I still receive all other emails from Riot Games, just not @accounts

I have tested that -

1. other Outlook emails work normally
2. Password reset works for other emails on other account

Answer (score 1):

I've got the exact same issue and I resolve it by forwarding emails I receive in my outlook mail to another ( It's the easiest and fastest solution ).

To make it work:

1. Log in to your Outlook.com account.
2. Click on the Gear icon on the upper right hand corner (beside your account icon).
3. Access More Outlook settings.
4. Under Mail section, go to Forwarding.
5. Inside the forwarding option, enable forwarding and add the forward email account.
6. Click Save.
7. Do the manipulation to make riotgames send you again a reset email.
8. Check in your forwarding email account the reset email (may also be in Junk folder)

Another way to resolve the issue I guess (not test it) should be to add noreply mails from riotgames to your "Safe Senders" in your settings.

Also Check first if it's not in your Junk folder or if you have any filter/rule settings enabled.